# Launch .exe installer via SSH (needs the admin access)

Tags: powershell, ssh, installation, admin

For this exemple, i tried to install Google Chrome with those lines and it worked well locally but not via SSH.

Here what worked and what did not :

**WORKING**

- I run my script locally (from an Administrator session, everything is fine)

*Download the installer*

```
 (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/375.126/chrome_installer.exe', 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\ChromeInstaller.exe')
```

*Lauch the installer*

```
 & 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\ChromeInstaller.exe' /silent /install
```

- I run the script (same as the previous line) on a SSH session (open a powershell, connect with user@ipAddress, type the script, launch and everything is good)
- To download the installer, there is no problem at all, it works fine :

**NOT WORKING**

- I run my script locally (from a normal session, so not Administrator, and it doesn't work, not a problem actually, I want to allow only the installation from the admin).
- Run the script directly from SSH like the following line (it supposed to be Administrator, I have the rights, and I am connected to the root user (with the admin rights).

  `ssh root@10.0.10.26 "& 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\ChromeInstaller.exe' /silent /install"`
- No errors, it is sent correctly but it has the same behaviour that the NoAdministrator shell.

Comment: Can you say more about the target system? `root` is a very uncommon username on Windows...

Comment: Hi, sure. The remote system has a Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC. The SSH server has the following version : OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5.

Comment: Is the installer a _GUI_ application? If so, it runs _asynchronously_. Try `"& 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Downloads\\ChromeInstaller.exe' /silent /install | Write-Output"` to force it run _synchronously_, after which you can check the automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable for the process exit code. As an aside: while it does no harm, there's no need to use ``\\`` in paths in PowerShell - just ``\`` will do.

Comment: Ah great thanks, it's working fine with the Write-Output pipe. Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks again guys.